# How does the cx and cy get calculated when the width and height of a SVG is not provided ?

Tags: svg

I was just going through this website **[HERE](http://circliful.pguso.de/)**, its basically a SVG plugin , i was just going through the source for the 1st circle and saw the following code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 194 186" class="circliful">undefined
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" class="border" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>
        <circle class="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="57" fill="none" stroke="#3498DB" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="140, 20000" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)"></circle>
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="28.5" fill="none"></circle>undefined
        <text class="timer" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110" style="font-size: 22px; undefined;" fill="#aaa">38%</text>
 </svg>
```

Now there is no height and width defined for this SVG so how exactly does the cx and cy  get callculated ??

Comment: I'm guessing its CSS class defines dimensions

Comment: Since the SVG has a viewBox the width and height default to 100% (of the SVG's container) allowing for preservation of the aspect ratio.